# Resize div height without white space at the bottom- Tailwind css

Tags: css

```css
.rightMidPicture{
background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/homepageRight.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:90%;
}


.leftMidPicture{
background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/greyandyellow1.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:90%;
}
```

```html
<div className='homepagePictures gap-4 inline-block'>
  <div className='leftMidPicture md:h-5/6 '>
  </div>
  <div className='rightMidPicture flex flex-col md:h-5/6 xl:h-5/6'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using an image for the background of each div, however when I reduced the height of the div the background changes but not the div itself. As a result I have a lot of white space below it, does anyone know how I can get rid of it?

Loosk like this currently:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're using a css library, use the inspect tool to check what css is being applied that might cause this issue. If that's not the case my guess would be background-position. Either way you provided too little information for someone else to debug it

Comment: I'm using tailwind css.

Comment: I noticed but tailwind is an extensive library, which I doubt anyone knows by heart. CSS as the name implies is cascading so there may be multiple styles written that cascade down onto your image element. Play around with chrome's inspect tool, select the element and check all the styles applied to it, only then will you find the cause of your issue. Once you do, isolate it, replicate it within the snippet and either you will already know how to fix it or someone will in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make the image larger than its size, tou need to set background-size property, because without it the image will be displayed with a maximum dimension equal to size of the image file.

E.g. `<div style="background-size: cover;"></div>`

```css
div{
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/120/120) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.has-background-size-property{
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="has-background-size-property"></div>
```

Comment: I already have my picture set to background size cover, I've added my css with what I had from before.

Comment: As Blye mentioned - we have little information. Try sending the URL if it's not local. By the way, if you have background-size: cover; so background-position:90%; will be ignored

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't URL. Background position is currently working with where I want the image to be shown. I'm unsure what else to help?

Comment: if you say that Background position working, so maybe background-size is ignorated. Try to add !important - 
background-size: cover !important;

Comment: Still no change! I've also tried using object-fit with img tag and still no use.